# Multi-threaded utility that logs some audit trails

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, synchronization

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded utility that logs some audit trails to the DB every 30 minutes, or whenever my storage data structure (a list in this case) exceeds a certain limit.

The code works well, but having said that, my manager said there *could* potentially be some issues in the method LogUserUsageData(...) where one thread tries to add a `UserUsage` object while another thread is in the lock trying to initialize the same list.

1. Should I be declaring my list as volatile?
2. Should I be thinking about double-locking techniques?

Can anybody throw more light on this?

```
namespace Utilities
{
    public class UserUsageStatistics
    {
        private SynchronizedCollection<UserUsage> _statisticsList;
        private readonly Thread _persistenceThread;
        private readonly string _flag = String.Empty;

        public UserUsageStatistics()
        {
            _statisticsList = new SynchronizedCollection<UserUsage>();
            _persistenceThread = new Thread(ThreadWork);
            _persistenceThread.Start();
        }

        public void LogUserUsageData(UserUsage userUsage)
        {
            if (_statisticsList.Count >= 100) PersistToDataStore();
            _statisticsList.Add(userUsage);
        }

        void ThreadWork()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                PersistToDataStore();
                Thread.Sleep(1800000);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Persist the data to the data store.
        /// </summary>
        void PersistToDataStore()
        {
            if (_statisticsList.Count == 0) return;
            try
            {
                SynchronizedCollection<UserUsage> tempList;
                lock (_flag)
                {
                    if (_statisticsList.Count == 0) return;

                    tempList = _statisticsList;
                    _statisticsList = new SynchronizedCollection<UserUsage>();
                }
                //TODO: Save to database
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning in the question early on. I am using .NET 3.5. ConcurrentQueue<T> won't be available here. Plans are to move our projects to 4.5, but only later this year.

Answer (score 4):

### DO NOT LOCK ON EMPTY STRING

In .NET every string is stored only once in the AppDomain so if you are locking on empty string everything will stop until you release the lock.

The correct syncroot can be:

```
private readonly object _flag = new object();
```

And yes you should use double check locking. The other thing is thati would use a ConcurrentQueue instead of SynchronizedCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will read up on ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: But why would I be better off using a queue rather than a list?

Comment: You can use the TryDequeu method to get elements out in a while(){} statement. If it return fail, you can save the exported objects from the queue so you don't need to create a new SyncronizedCollection when you are saving. If you will use a ConcurrentQueue you would not need to have any locking mechanism.

Comment: It's not generally true that every string is stored only once, that applies only to interned strings. But locking on `string.Empty` is a very bad idea nevertheless.

Comment: Better yet, in this case, the additional object can be forgone and locking on `_statisticsList` itself should be sufficient.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I would think twice before locking on a field whose value changes. (I'm not saying it's wrong, but I do think it makes the code harder to reason about.)

Comment: @svick Oh, ick. Yeah, I didn't see the reassignment at first.

Answer (score 4):

- As @PeterKiss correctly mentioned you should never lock on objects beyond your control ([`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), remarks section).
- your code is not thread-safe as you may loose some of the entries (one thread may be waiting on a call to `_statisticsList.Add` method while the other starts and runs to completion the `PersistToDataStore` method)
- Use `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>`, it will allow you to re-use the same collection instead of creating a new one (causing synchronisation issues)
- Use `System.Threading.Timer` class to run a method at specified intervals instead of manually creating a new thread.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my code to use    System.Threading.Timer instead of Thread.Sleep(), as well as locked on an object instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

You should never do this. You should catch only the exceptions that you're expecting. And if you really need to catch any exception, at least log it.

Comment: Agreed. I was going to take care of that later, once I figured out the threading-related code.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void ThreadWork()
> {
>   while (true)
>   {
>     PersistToDataStore();
>     Thread.Sleep(1800000);
>   }
> }
> ```

This is not correct, because such code will span additional Thread in application. I suppose there is more scheduled tasks than only PersistToDataStore every 30 minutes. 
In a long run there will be a lot of threads that just sleeping. It is a complex task for OS to allocate and execute new Thread.

You should use System.Threading.Timer:

```
 public UserUsageStatistics()
    {
        _statisticsList = new SynchronizedCollection<UserUsage>();
        _persistenceTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(PersistToDataStore, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    }
```

In this case ThreadWork method will not be needed anymore. And .Net Framework will execute method on available thread from an application thread pool.